# Ajax request to python is not returning anything

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, ajax

My goal is to get the result from `get_maps()` in a separate python script `~/mapsinterpeter`. The code below doesn't console.log() anything, despite me telling him to do, when its done. (I want to use `[year.value, mapdict.catvalue]` as arguments for the function)

```
function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    if(year.value === "" || cat.value === "") {
        msg.textContent = "Please fill out the fields"
        msg.classList.add("error");
    } else {
        msg.textContent = ""
        msg.classList.remove("error");
        const catvalue = cat.value
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "~/mapsinterpeter.py",
            dataType: "python",
            data: {param: [year.value, mapdict.catvalue]}
        }).done(function(o) {
            list = o
            console.log(list)
        });
        year.value = ""
        cat.value = ""
    } 
}

//Python code:

def get_maps(g):
# code code to build the list "fl" 
    return fl.append({"maps": count, "totalelm": telem})
```

Comment: Open devtools and check the network tab after making your AJAX request. You should be able to see the status code and response text which will give you some information to be able to debug the problem

Comment: Thank you! I was able to see that the problem was the path file!